# TikZ: is there a better way to represent the following node content

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Consider the code below:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font = \scriptsize] at (-3.5, 4) {Position of $S_2$ when};
  \node[font = \scriptsize] at (-3.5, 3.7) {$S_1$ reaches $C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used two nodes to write short explanation of a point in a figure I am constructing.  However, I had to play around with the set up so they weren't spaced vertically too far a part and the second node was centered on the content of the first node.  Is there a better way to this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, `\node […,align=center] at (…) {Position of $S_2$ when \\ $S_1$ reaches $C$};`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks.  I didn't know I could use \\ in a node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Qrrbrbirlbel pointed, you can use `\\` to break lines inside a `node` if you also use `align` option. Without it,  `\\` has no effect as is shown in top node below.

If you don't want to insert `\\` every time, you can combine `text width` and `align` options. With them, `latex` will break lines according its rules. You'll find some examples below.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (a) {Position of $S_2$ when \\ $S_1$ reaches $C$};

\node[draw,text width=3cm, below=of a] (b) {Position of $S_2$ when \\ $S_1$ reaches $C$};

\node[draw,align=center, below=of b] (c) {Position of $S_2$ when \\ $S_1$ reaches $C$};

\node[draw,text width=3cm, align=right, below=of c] (d) {Position of $S_2$ when $S_1$ reaches $C$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is sad that PSTricks cannot do it without `parbox` or its variants. The following is with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,3)
\rput(5,2){\parbox{10cm}{\centering Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns.\\ Karl's students do not care about arrow tips.}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]